# Looking for good scale factor for converting log to 8.8 fixed point

Tags: math, fixed-point, natural-logarithm

I have a range of numbers in `(0, 1]`

I would like to take the natural log of these numbers, and then store as 8.8
fixed point.

My foruma is  `K*ln(x) + (1<<16)`

but I am not sure what the best value is for `K`  .

My thinking is that if `x` doubles, then `ln(x)` increases by `ln(2)`, so the fixed point value should increase by 1 in fixed point (i.e. 256)

So, this would mean `K = 256/ln(2)`

Does this make sense?

Comment: Would that be [Q8.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic#Notation) as in 16 bit quantity with 8 bit integer and 8 bit fractional part? Is the `(1 << 16)` meant to convert the negative numbers to positive ones? As you are aware, `ln(0)` is essentially negative infinity, so if most of your numbers are from the (0, 0.01] range, you'd probably pick a different scale than if most were from the (0.9, 1] range. Do you have details on the distribution or similar information to decide which information you'd rather loose?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Q8.8 it is.But, I am not sure what kind of distribution the range of numbers follows.

Comment: Some example inputs and expected results would help clarify.

Answer (score 1):

As *x* approaches 0, ln(*x*) will diverge to negative infinity. So you are essentially trying to map an infinite domain to a finite range.

If you do so in a linear way, you have to cut off at some point. If you choose your cut-off at too low a value, you'll be wasting precision for the numbers you represent. If you choose to high a cut-off, too many values will be clamped to the minimal element of the range. Without knowledge about the distribution of the point, it will be very hard to guess a suitable balance here.

So perhaps you could apply a non-linear map instead of the linear one you proposed. Something like the exponential function? Which would mean you'd actually store *x* instead of ln(*x*). So I'd say if you want to store values from [0,1) in 16 bit without too much loss of information, you'd just use Q0.16, i.e. all the digits in the fractional part. For (0,1] you can either store 1 − *x* or do a special case for *x* = 1 so that you encode that as 0 instead. If you have Q8.8 numbers, you'd multiply your numbers by 2<sup>8</sup> = 256 first, but if you have access to the bit representation that multiplication would be a waste of time.

I guess you had a reason you'd want to store logarithms, so this answer may not be what you were hoping for. I don't see an easier way around the underlying problem, though, so you may have to reconsider some of your ideas.